# Simple Regex from HTML

Tags: regex

I have the following code grabbed from a webpage source code:

```
<span>41,396</span>
```

And the following regex:

```
("<span>.*</span>")
```

Which returns

```
<span>New Users</span>
```

However, I don't want to have the  tags in the results. I've tried  a few things, but Regular Expressions are new to me.

More so than this I need to get the Regex for the following code:

```
<span>41,396</span>
</span>
<span class="levelColumn">
<span>2,150</span>
</span>
<span class="xpColumn">
<span>161,305,807</span>
```

I was thinking this may involve line breaks and more, which is why I threw this is separately.

Comment: Which language are your trying to implement this?

Comment: What do you want the regex to do with the code snippet?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use regex to pars (X)HTML: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) on a discussion why. You'd better use an (X)HTML parser and process your (X)HTML programmatically. Which programming language are you using?

Comment: This is in VB.net using a HTTPwebrequest. It returns the result into a list box. The program is fine apart from know how to regex it. I also have no idea what a parser is or means.

Comment: Do not use the greedy dot-star! It will erroneously match _much_ more than you bargained for. (To match a simple SPAN containing only numbers and whitespace, use something like this instead: `"<span>[\d.,\s]+</span>`) _Say what you mean, mean what you say!_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like

```
<span( class=\".+\")?>(.*)</span>
```

And then get capture group 2 for the tag's body. But be aware that regular expressions are NOT good for parsing HTML/XML. What would happen if you had nested `<span>` tags?

If the input gets even the slightest bit more complicated than what you've shown, look for an HTML parser and try using that instead.

Comment: The reason for just using <span> as the regex was just for my own experiement. But I thought if you used the whole 2nd part of the code, it would would fine for grabbing data from a table?

Comment: @Hayden: Ok, so maybe look into an HTML parser. You *could* do this with regex, but it will be painful.

Comment: Alright, I haven't managed to get any of the answers working right. So I'll take a look. Thanks to everyone who helped. =). Seems it's going to be hard to find a single thing about what a html parser is.

Comment: @Hayden: What language/platform are you using? Here's a parser for Java: http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Hayden: Ah, you're using .NET. Have you tried this one? http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what to do with that. Threads I find on it are in C# or are also having problems with it.

Comment: @Hayden: If it's .NET you should be able to use it even from within a VB project. The syntax will look different but you're using a DLL, so it shouldn't be a big problem. I haven't tried using this library from VB.NET it myself though, so, I can't talk from my own experiences, just my expectations...

Comment: Do not use the greedy dot-star/dot-plus! This will erroneously match much more than you bargained for!

Comment: Its ok, I don't understand any of this stuff. So I came up with a workaround. I just get the string as I have been getting, but I just remove the <span> tags with the .replace function (setting to "")

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing group differently to get the value instead of tag + value

```
"<span>(.*)</span>"
```

Think to use a HTML parsing library in your language of choice if regex become more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know regex will lookup line by line, but you could have an expression that would work that out.

Try: `<span>(.*)</span>`

You should be able to retrieve the information you want with `\1`

In the case of `<span class="xpColumn">` it would just not match and `\1` would be empty..

Cheers :)